# Calculate weighted average of percentages

Tags: python, math, statistics

I have a problem to solve in order to make the correct calculations. I have a list of percentages for the performance of a specific marketing channel before and after specific actions and I want to make the percentage increment. I can't just take the average of the following values I have to take the weighted average of the values.

Values below are percentages ( 0.10 is 10% )

```
percentage_list_after_actions = [ 0.10, 0.3, 0.16, 0.22 ] 
percentage_list_before_actions = [ 0.14, 0.26, 0.12, 0.25 ]
```

Which is the best way of doing that?

Is the weighted average the correct metric as we have percentages or I have to take the moving_average/rolling_average?

Answer (score 0):

Create the function that calculates this.

```
def weighted_average_m1(distribution, weights):
  
    numerator = sum([distribution[i]*weights[i] for i in range(len(distribution))])
    denominator = sum(weights)
    
    return round(numerator/denominator,2)

weighted_average_m1(distribution, weights)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont have weights its just the percentages.